# How to broadcast over adhoc wifi using the python sockets library

Tags: python, sockets, wifi, raspberry-pi3, adhoc

Summer researcher using Raspbian and Python 3.5.

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to broadcast a message using the sockets library to other Pis (same model) over their shared ad-hoc network. All of the Pis can ping the others over the ad hoc network. The Pis can also communicate using pretty standard client-server code and the [python socket library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html). However, when I try to **broadcast** a message, the Pis give a "Network is unreachable" message (full error down below).

A grad student I'm working with said that the script he provided me expects the server to be run in infrastructure mode, and configuration for ad-hoc mode is required to make it work correctly. This is confirmed, as I have successfully run the code on a desktop. I have poured over man pages and stackoverflow, and can't seem to find resources for how to configure socket broadcasts for ad-hoc networks. Any thoughts? All help is appreciated.

**Broadcast function:**

```
def broadcast(self, frequency, port):

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    server.settimeout(0.2)

    while True:
        server.sendto("GET OUT OF MY SWAMP", ('<broadcast>', port))
        print("message sent...")
        time.sleep(frequency)
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myServer.py", line 31, in <module>
    s.broadcast(float(frequency),int(port))
  File "myServer.py", line 22, in broadcast
    server.sendto("GET OUT OF MY SWAMP", ('<broadcast>', port))
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

My gateway was 0.0.0.0. You can view your gateway by running **sudo route -n**. By running **sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.112** (The Pi's IP address), I'm now able to broadcast "GET OUT OF MY SWAMP" to any device connected to the same port and network. My routing table after the add command looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref   Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.112   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0       0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0       0 wlan0
```

Still unsure how to permanently add a gateway to a device; the gateway seems to reset after a reboot. Please feel free to offer further questions or clarifications.